# Not well-formed error message in FF

Tags: html, xhtml, ashx, well-formed

My site just started to behave strange... In FF 8 I get this error (could be after I upgraded my FF, not sure):

```
Error: not well-formed
Source File: http://example.mysite.com/ws_flexihandler.ashx/functionname
Line: 21, Column: 5
Source Code:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If I refresh the page by pressing CTRL+F5 it loads fine. Chrome and IE does not have this problem and what is really strange is that it works well (also in FF 8) when running locally on my development computer.

Not sure what source code I should include in this question as I feel it might not have to do with my code...

Comment: The best would be to post a URL. Until then: It looks like a problem with not well formed X(HT)ML. Does your page validate? Does it use AJAX with XML and is that XML correct?

Comment: If you do not wish to give out your full source code, create a simplified version of the code, where the problem still exists, and post that for us.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML-file is not XHTML, not well formed. Press CTRL+F5, and view source - the problem lies in there.

I am using FF8, and when I access a page that is not well-formed, I get no errors. You have turned on some debugging feature, that requires strict xhtml.